Finite $C^\ast$-algebras
I saw in some places that (1) is given for the definition of finite $C^\ast$-algebras. Some others consider (2). It is obvious that (2) implies (1). But I could not prove the converse. Could anyone comment on it? Thanks.
Let $A$ be a unital $C^\ast$-algebra.

For every $u \in A$, $uu^\ast = 1_A$ implies $u^\ast u = 1_A$.
For every $x, y \in A$, $xy = 1_A$ implies $yx = 1_A$.


Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

Suppose (1) holds and $xy = 1_A$. Let $A$ acts faithfully on some Hilbert space $H$. Then $xy = 1_A$ implies $y$ must be bounded below - indeed, for any $h \in H$,
$$\|h\| = \|xyh\| \leq \|x\|\|yh\|$$
So, $\|yh\| \geq \frac{1}{\|x\|}\|h\|$. Then $|y|$ is bounded below as well, since $\||y|h\| = \|yh\|$. Thus, the spectrum of $|y|$ is bounded away from $0$, so it is invertible. Now, consider the operator $u^\ast = y|y|^{-1}$, we have,
$$uu^\ast = |y|^{-1}y^\ast y|y|^{-1} = |y|^{-1}|y|^2|y|^{-1} = 1_A$$
Hence, $u^\ast u = 1_A$, i.e., $y|y|^{-2}y^\ast = 1_A$. Therefore,
$$x = x1_A = xy|y|^{-2}y^\ast = 1_A|y|^{-2}y^\ast = |y|^{-2}y^\ast$$
Thus, $yx = y|y|^{-2}y^\ast = 1_A$.

Thank you very much.

@Alex If you find the answer satisfactory, you can accept the answer using the checkmark to the left.

Thanks lot again for your comment, David. Just want to ask you a quick question. How can we deduce the invertibility of |y| from being bounded away from 0? For example, take a positive element f in C([0, 1]) such f is zero from 0 to 1/10, f is linear from 1/10 to 1/2 and f is equal to 1 from 1/2 to 1.  Now it is clear that ||f|| is bounded away from 0. But f is not an invertible element of C([0, 1]).

It's not the norm being bounded away from $0$, but the spectrum. It's a general fact that, for a positive operator $A$, if $|Ah| \geq C|h|$ for some $C > 0$, then the spectrum of $A$ is contained in $[C, \infty)$. This can be proved using spectral theorem - $A$ can be essentially regarded as multiplication by $x$ on its spectrum, so if its spectrum intersects with $[0, C)$, then you can find some nonzero vector $h$ in the spectral projection corresponding to $[0, C - \epsilon]$ for some $\epsilon > 0$, but then $|Ah| \leq (C - \epsilon)|h|$, which is a contradiction.

(Just to prove invertibility, there is also an easier way if you're not familiar with spectral theorem: bounded below implies the range is closed and it is injective. Since $A$ is self-adjoint, being injective implies it has dense range. Closed range and dense range imply $A$ is surjective. So $A$ is bijective and thus invertible.)
